# Add notes and/or footnotes in reference

Tags: bibliographies, books

I would like to add a paragraph at the beginning of my reference list. Alternatively, I would like to add footnote right after the word "Bibliography". Is there an easy way to do these two things, please? To add reference list, I use the following commands.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{reference}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\bibsection` and `\bibpreamble` provided by `natbib` (looks like you are using it)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\nocite{*}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\renewcommand\bibpreamble{This is some text}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{\bibname\footnote{Some foot note}}\markboth{\leftmark}{\bibname}}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]